# Laravel 8 view layouts.app not found when calling route('login')

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I have been pulling my hair off for the last 2 hours to find a solution to the error view[layouts.app] not found when calling route('login').

For some reason, I have renamed all the instances of `layouts.app` to `dashboard.app` in all the auth files/folders.  url/login works fine by finding the correct file auth.login.blade.php.

In the routes/web.php I only have one line to define the auth routes:

```
Auth::routes();
```

If I click the link `register` in the `login page`, it gives me that error (the same happen if I call url/register):

```
View [layouts.app] not found.
```

from the following line in auth.register.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Have a login</a>
```

When searching for `layouts.app` in the whole Laravel 8 project, no instance is found.  So I guessed it must be cached... Even after all these commands, no success.

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
delete content of folder bootstrap/cache
```

If I understand correctly, route('register') display the file auth.register.blade.php as well as route route('password.request') displays the file auth.password.request.blade.php (but I don't where these routes are defined)... so why is route('login') still references a filename that is not in the project?

Can someone please help me figure out this?

Comment: You cleared the config and route cache. Can you please also clear view cache. You may clear all caches using `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Search for `@extends('layouts.app')`
its the default Laravel layout that all default views extend from it.

Comment: As I explained in my post, I find no occurence of 'layouts.app'... so I implemented a way around.